# Using jQuery load(),callback function run twice?

Tags: jquery

It's in a php framework, I import load.js to sidebar template.I need some data from other page to every sidebar.load.js like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.fleft').load('home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=credit&showcredit=1 #cred_update',function(){
          console.log(2)
      })
})
```

console.log run twice, home.php page is not import load.js.

Comment: the page seems load only once

Comment: `load` method is _deprecated_.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the class fleft?

Answer (score 0):

redirecting by hash bang. ex: `/foo.php#/bar` to `/foo.php#/baz`
or using `window.location.replace(forward)`

Comment: i know, there are two .fleft